# How to set values for AbstractComposeView using XML?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Composable wrapped in `AbstractComposeView` to be used in XML.
How to set values to this view.

Example,

**Composable and AbstractComposeView**

```
class MyComposeView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : AbstractComposeView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var titleText by mutableStateOf("Default text")

    var titleValue: String
        get() = titleText
        set(value) {
            titleText = value
        }


    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        ListItem(
            text = titleText,
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListItem(
    text: String,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
        )
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewActivity">

    <com.example.android.MyComposeView
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
findViewById<MyComposeView>(R.id.my_view).titleValue = "From Activity"
```

This gives the intended result, but how to achieve the same without any code changes in the activity?

Something like `app:titleText`? (Tried this didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

As for a regular custom view, you will need to rely on attribut set.

First create it in `res > values > attrs.xml`
Somethings like:

```xml
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="MyComposeView">
       <attr name="titleText" format="string" />
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then apply it in your MyComposeView class

```kotlin
init {
    context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.MyComposeView,
            0, 0).apply {

        try {
            titleText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.MyComposeView_ titleText).toString()
        } finally {
            recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

Références:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/create-view#customattr 
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/create-view#applyattr